# Javascript application memory handling

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, memory, browser

i have the below JS:

```
var z = function(){
return "string";
}

var x = function(){
      var y = new z();
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = y;
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      /*
            my code…hundreds of other functions. Entire app is js all data comes through sockets and elements created using JS
     */
}
```

I have a couple of questions which might sound stupid but I am hoping not.

So inside 'x' is 'y' and 'div'. Now if these 2 elements are only used there do they still 'live' inside the JS on the browser or do they vanish?
Basically do i need to set them to null to avoid any extra memory from being used on useless items.

Also I wrote like 25k of lines using JS and all the elements are created using JS. The app stays up for like 9 hours until they close it and it starts all over again on another day.
 But for those hours I am worried it will be getting slower due to its size. Could this be true?

Comment: hundreds of other functions inside that `x` function is apparently a bad practise.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Do I really need to cite something about code modularity? I think it's common sense.

Comment: @Bergi: Well, his code isn't necessarily not modular just because he's got lots of functions inside `x`. It's difficult to know without seeing it. (Also I think I misunderstood your comment: you said it's "apparently" a bad practice, by which I thought you meant "I've read something specific that says it's a bad practice; I'm not sure myself.")

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your applications memory usage, every time `x()` is called it creates a temporary instance of the local variable `y`. This is discarded once the function has been run to completion.
`X` is an anonymous function that gives it a new scope . New variables will be inside this scope, also `this` will become the function object and you can access the global scope with `window`.

There will be differences in how the various browsers handle this kind of situation but the result is pretty much the same.
Browsers are always being optimised to make them more efficient at handling memory as well as faster. They are optimising scope chain lookup costs away too which should result in improved performance.

Due to nature of your anonymous function `x()` there may be moments where the browser runs its "garbage collection" which could slow or stop script execution but after that it should run without problems.
The Javascript engines inside the modern browsers can handle incredible processing as many libraries (such as jquery) require large amounts of processing.

I would not worry too much about Javascript engines and your 25k lines, it is more down to your code itself and what it is doing.

Comment: I was thinking it was ok but now i am now more confident.
Firefox is using 8900mb memory after 5/6 hours running, but new version uses only 400mb, still quite alot but better than before. thanks

Comment: Wow, that's a fast and long answer!

Comment: @Bergi posted my first answer but then edited it to add more bits :). my technique.

Comment: @CraigTaub: Mine as well, but you've got it nearly ready in less than 1:30 after the question was posted :-)

Comment: above i meant 900mb not 8900mb